# is it possible to upload a file of more than 4MB in salesforce custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on a ligtning component to upload the salesforce attachment more than 4 MB.Is there any way to do if not can anyone explain the limitations around that or any salesforce documentation.

Comment: Well, if you are inquiring about the 4MB limit, you must have stumbled upon an error. Have you tried looking for documentation? Please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Oh, and by the way, welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I had encountered the error when tried a file more than 4 MB. Do you know if there is any salesforce documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find plenty of resources [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_upload_share.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.14) under Upload and Share Files. If you need documentation, I would suggest you use the [H&T porta](https://help.salesforce.com/)l for future reference.

here is a quick guide on limits and file attachments from the doc:

> Attachments related list   25 MB for file attachments 2 GB for feed
>   attachments
>
> Documents tab  5 MB 20 KB for a custom-app logo
>
> Salesforce CRM Content
>   2 GB (including headers) when uploaded
>   via Chatter REST API
>
> 2 GB (including headers) when uploaded via REST
>   API
>
> 38 MB when uploaded via SOAP API 10 MB when uploaded via BULK API
>
> 10 MB for Google Docs 10 MB when uploaded via Visualforce
>
> Salesforce files  2 GB
>
> Salesforce Knowledge  5 MB for attachments